# Animations & Transitions lagging in safari

Tags: html, css, vue.js, safari, tailwind-css

I have created some very basic transitions and animations for my application they work smoothly on Chrome and Firefox but on Safari they lagg. This doesn't happen to every animated/transitioned element but only to a few.

### Transition:

Here is a snippet of the transition that laggs:

```html
<aside
  class="hidden lg:block h-[85vh] p-8 rounded-3xl bg-gradient-to-t from-blue-500
  to-blue-900 text-white transition-width duration-150 ease-in-out sticky top-4"
  :class="isSidebarCollapsed ? 'w-24' : 'w-52'"
>
  <div class="flex h-full w-full flex-col">
    <nav>
      <div
        class="flex items-center gap-x-4 mb-12 cursor-pointer"
        @click.prevent="toggleSidebarCollapse"
      >
        <div class="rounded-full bg-blue-500 p-[3px]">
          <AppButton
            class="w-8 h-8 items-center justify-center rounded-full bg-white text-blue-900
            border border-blue-900 md:flex"
            :title="isSidebarCollapsed ? 'Uitvouwen' : 'Samenvouwen'"
            button-size="icon-sm"
            theme="secondary"
          >
            <FontAwesomeIcon
              :icon="['fas', 'chevron-left']"
              size="sm"
              class="transition-transform duration-150 ease-in-out"
              :class="{'scale-x-[-1]': isSidebarCollapsed}"
            />
          </AppButton>
        </div>
        <span v-if="!isSidebarCollapsed" class="absolute left-20">Sluit</span>
      </div>
      <SideNavigation class="mb-4" />
    </nav>
  </div>
</aside>
```

---

### Animation

Here is a snippet of the animation that laggs:

```html
<template>
  <div
    class="z-0 h-10 w-24 cursor-pointer rounded-full bg-blue-200 p-2"
  >
    <div 
      class="relative z-20 flex h-full w-full items-center justify-between
      px-3 text-blue-700"
    >
      <FontAwesomeIcon
        size="1x"
        :icon="['fas', leftIcon]"
        class="transition-colors duration-300 ease-in-out"
        :class="{'text-white': !modelValue}"
      />
      <FontAwesomeIcon
        size="1x"
        :icon="['fas', rightIcon]"
        class="transition-colors duration-300 ease-in-out"
        :class="{'text-white': modelValue}"
      />
    </div>
    <div
      class="relative z-10 -mt-6 h-full w-10 rounded-full bg-blue-700"
      :class="{'slideRight': modelValue, 'slideLeft': !modelValue}"
    />
  </div>
</template>

<style lang="css" scoped>
@keyframes slideLeft {
  0% { @apply w-10; margin-left: 50%; }
  50% { width: 100%; margin-left: 0%; }
  100% { @apply w-10; }
}
@keyframes slideRight {
  0% { @apply w-10; }
  50% { width: 100%; margin-left: 0%; }
  100% { @apply w-10; margin-left: 50%; }
}

.slideLeft {
  animation: slideLeft 0.3s ease-in-out;
}
.slideRight {
  animation: slideRight 0.3s ease-in-out;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
</style>
```

---

### What i've tried

Initially i had used the tailwind-class `transition-all` but tried specifying the properties this did not fix the issue.

I've also tried using `will-animate-[width]` etc. but neither this worked.